# Why two of my classifiers cannot predict many labels?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, random-forest, mlp

I try to compare the classifiers RandomForest (RF), SupportVectorMachine (SVM) and Multilayer Perceptron (MLP) looking at their `classification_report`. It is a multi classification on categorical data.
Same data (378443 entries, 7 columns)
same  y_tain,
same y_test,.
I examined my y_train and y_test with:

```
 from collections import Counter
    Counter(y_train)
    Counter(y_test)
```

I see that both have the same 31 classes.

```
OUTPUT Counter(y_train):             OUTPUT Counter(y_test)
Counter({'Class 1': 201096,        Counter({'Class 1': 133917,
         'Class 2': 24109,                  'Class 11': 5,
         'Class 3': 731,                    'Class 2': 16167,
         'Class 4': 851,                    'Class 3': 475,
         'Class 5': 60,                     'Class 4': 628,
         'Class 6': 7,                      'Class 8': 7,
         'Class 7': 19,                     'Class 12': 19,
         'Class 8': 3,                      'Class 21': 3,
         'Class 9': 12,                     'Class 25': 10,
         'Class 10': 7,                     'Class 18': 6,
         'Class 11': 5,                     'Class 9': 12,
         'Class 12': 28,                    'Class 5': 41,
         'Class 13': 5,                     'Class 16': 4,
         'Class 14': 8,                     'Class 7': 14,
         'Class 15': 9,                     'Class 17': 3,
         'Class 16': 6,                     'Class 30': 3,
         'Class 17': 7,                     'Class 26': 4,
         'Class 18': 4,                     'Class 27': 4,
         'Class 19': 6,                     'Class 14': 2,
         'Class 20': 5,                     'Class 28': 5,
         'Class 21': 7,                     'Class 13': 5,
         'Class 22': 6,                     'Class 24': 9,
         'Class 23': 7,                     'Class 15': 7,
         'Class 24': 15,                    'Class 31': 5,
         'Class 25': 10,                    'Class 10': 3,
         'Class 26': 10,                    'Class 23': 3,
         'Class 27': 6,                     'Class 29': 1,
         'Class 28': 5,                     'Class 22': 4,
         'Class 29': 9,                     'Class 20': 5,
         'Class 30': 7,                     'Class 6': 3,
         'Class 31': 5})                    'Class 19': 4})
```

But I get this warning when printing classification_report(y_train, y_pred):

> UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and
>   being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.   'precision',
>   'predicted', average, warn_for)

which means that not all the labels are included in y_pred, i.e. there are some labels in y_test that the classifier never predicts.

With RF, everything works well (just one class gets 0.00 in the classification_report for precision and recall).

The classification_report of SVM and MLP contains 0.00s in half of the classes.

MLP can predict ***13 classes*** (more than 0.00 in Precision/Recall): `class 1,2,3,4, 6, 8,9, 12, 14, 20,21, 23, 25`.

All my Code:

```
 #data is imported

Y = data['class']
data=data.drop['class']
labEn = {}
#LabelEncoding for cols
for x in range(len(data.columns)):
    #creating the LabelEncoder for col x 
    labEn[x] = LabelEncoder()
    dfPre[data.columns[x]] = labEn[x].fit_transform(data[data.columns[x]])
    #for unknown labels
    labEn[x].classes_ = np.append(labEn[x].classes_, '-unknown-')

X = data
X.shape #Output:(378443, 7)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)
    ###### amount of train and test data####################
X_train.shape, y_train.shape
    #Output: (227065, 7)
(227065,)
X_test.shape, y_test.shape
    #Output: (151378, 7)
(151378,)

from collections import Counter
print(Counter(y_train))
print(Counter(y_test))

##RF
rfclf = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight = 'balanced')
rfclf.fit(X_train,  y_train)

y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(rfclf, X_train, y_train, cv=3)
y_test_pred=cross_val_predict(rfclf, X_test, y_test, cv=3)

print(classification_report(y_train, y_train_pred))

print(classification_report(y_test, y_test_pred))

##for SVM and MLP: Scaling data
start_time_standardscaler = time.time()
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train) 

X_train_scaled=scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test) 

#for svm: One Hot Encoder - I also tried it without!
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
enc.fit(X_train_scaled)
X_train_X_test_ohencoded=enc.transform(X_train_scaled)
X_test_ohencoded=enc.transform(X_test_scaled)

##SVM
svmclf=svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma='scale')
svmclf.fit(X_train_scaled,y_train)#also tried X_train_ohencoded,y_train)

y_train_pred_scaled = cross_val_predict(svmclf, X_train_scaled, y_train, cv=10)
#y_train_pred_ohencoded = cross_val_predict(svmclf, X_train_ohencoded, y_train, cv=10)


print(classification_report(y_train, y_train_pred_scaled))
#print(classification_report(y_train, y_train_pred_ohencoded))

print(classification_report(y_test, y_test_pred))
#print(classification_report(y_test, y_test_pred_ohencoded))

##MLP
mlpclf = MLPClassifier(solver='adam', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(50, 100), random_state=1)
mlpclf.fit(X_train_scaled,y_train)

y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(mlpclf, X_train_scaled, y_train, cv=10)
y_test_pred=cross_val_predict(rfclf, X_test_scaled, y_test, cv=3)

print(classification_report(y_train, y_train_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_test_pred))



##Prediction
#works well since the 5 classes all classifiers could train has to be predicted here (how lucky)

#newdata is imported
#Scaler from above is used 
newdata_scaled=scaler.transform(newdata)
#Encoder from above is used
newdata_enc=enc.transform(newdata_scaled)

rfclf.predict(newdata)
svmclf.predict(newdata_enc)
mlpclf.predict(newdata_scaled)
```

Comment: How large is your training data set? How is the distribution of the 31 classes in the training set? Your model probably fail because there is too little data it can train from for some classes. Also how many features you have?

Comment: @cho_uc I updated my question. You can see the distribution of the classes in the first table. Trainingdata (X_train.shape): 227065, Testdata (X_test.shape): 151378, Features: 7.

Answer (score 0):

You have a severe imbalance data set with 99% of dataset classified in only 2 out of 31 classes. Other than the size of dataset, the distribution variations (percentage of each class) is also important. Your model will tend to overfit to class with higher percentage because it will get high accuracy there.

One way to fix it is to generate synthetic samples for the minority class.
**SMOTE** (Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique) can be applied to your data through`imblearn` package for python.

You can go [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/having-an-imbalanced-dataset-here-is-how-you-can-solve-it-1640568947eb) for more detail

Comment: thanks a lot! 
Btw, does it mean it will often predict the class which is the biggest class in the training data because it overfits on it?

Comment: Yes correct, it will tend to predict the biggest class. That's why you got 0 results for smaller class. You may also want to tweak further: reconsider if you really need that much classes in your model (i.e if 5 classes can already represent what you want instead of 31 classes)